# Is there any way to get Inbox by Gmail to uppercase suggested reminders?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

When I type in the text box to create a reminder, the keyboard (Google Keyboard) automatically uppercases it, but the suggestions are lowercase, and fixing them to be consistently uppercase deletes the associated hints such as links to contacts' emails and such. Is there any way to make the suggestions uppercase?

Running Android 4.4.4 on a Motorola Droid Maxx
 with Google keyboard version 5.1.23.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: OK, filled in as much as I could being on desktop at the moment.

Comment: Filled in the rest of the details from my phone.

Comment: On Marshmallow i dont lose email address because of this

Comment: Lose email address? What do you mean? I didn't type an email address to begin with.

Comment: Sorry..i meant I have no problems with *associated hints such as links to contacts' emails* as mentioned in the question, so it maybe something that got fixed in later versions of Android

Comment: Oh, right, I totally forgot what I wrote! Sorry!